# Calculate $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}xdx$ by integration of a suitable function along given paths

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

How can I calculate $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}xdx$$ by integration of a suitable function along the following paths:[image: paths]

where $R$ and $\varepsilon$ are the radius of the shown outer and inner semicircle, respectively. This seems to be quite interesting. How would one do that?

Comment: This is going to be a duplicate post.

Comment: As @Tunk-Fey says, this is bound to have been answered before. But searching for it might not be so easy … Meanwhile, the short answer is to integrate $e^{iz}/z$ around the given path, find that the integral around the big semicircle goes to zero, and the one around the small semicircle has a limit that is easy to find, while the integrals along the straight segments will reduce to $i$ times the integral you are looking for when you write $e^{ix}$ in terms of trigonometric functions and take symmetries into account. Try it yourself, it's good exercise.

Comment: (Actually, the estimates get a bit easier if you replace the big semicircle by three sides of a square.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Why I am allowed to make such a replacement?

Comment: Because of the Cauchy integral theorem. The function has no singularities on or within the closed curve formed by the semicircle and the three sides of a square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}xdx = 
\frac 12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin x}xdx =
\frac 12 \Im\left\{\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ix}}xdx\right\}
$$
Where $\Im$ denotes the imaginary part.
Let $\gamma_R$ be the outer semicircle, let $\gamma_I$ be the part of the contour on the real line (from right to left), and let $\gamma _\epsilon$ be the inner semicircle (clockwise).  Since there are no singularities inside the contour, we have
$$
\int_{\gamma_R} + \int_{\gamma_I} + \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} = 0
$$
You should be able to argue that $\int_{\gamma_R} \to 0$, so that
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left(\int_{\gamma_I} + \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} \right) = 0\implies\\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x}\,dx = \frac 12 \cdot 2 \pi i \cdot \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{z},z=0 \right)
$$
To compute $\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{z},z=0 \right)$, we take the $1/z$ coefficient of the Laurent-expansion of $e^{iz}/z$ centered at zero.  The expansion is given by
$$
\frac{1}{z}\left(1 + (iz) + (iz)^2/2 + (iz)^3/6 + \cdots\right) = 
\frac 1z + i - z/2 - iz^2/6 + \cdots
$$
So that $\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{z},z=0 \right) = 1$.

So, we conclude that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x}\,dx = \frac 12 \cdot 2 \pi i = \pi i
$$
So, taking the imaginary part and halving the result, we conclude that
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}xdx = \pi/2
$$

---

Proof that $\int_{\gamma_R} \to 0:$ In fact, this follows from [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma)

We may parameterize the integral as
$$
\int_{\gamma_R} = \int_0^\pi \frac{e^{i Re^{i\theta}}}{Re^{i\theta}} iR\,d\theta
$$
We note that
$$
\left|\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{i Re^{i\theta}}}{Re^{i\theta}} iR\,d\theta\right|
\leq
\int_0^\pi \left|\frac{e^{i Re^{i\theta}}}{Re^{i\theta}} iR\right|\,d\theta
=
\int_0^\pi \left|e^{i Re^{i\theta}}\right|\,d\theta \\
=
\int_0^\pi \left|e^{i R\cos \theta}e^{-R\sin \theta}\right|\,d\theta
=
\int_0^\pi e^{-R\sin \theta}\,d\theta 
$$
The fact that this approaches $0$ as $R \to \infty$ is proven in the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma).

Comment: Please explain to me what's meant by "no singularities inside the contour" ...

Comment: There are no poles in the region whose border is given by these contours

Comment: What's $\text{Res}(\ldots )$ and why is the sum of the contour-integrals $0$?

Comment: The integral is zero because of the [Cauchy-Goursat theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem)

Comment: Also, see my latest edit for an explanation of the residue.

Comment: Thanks, I used to know that. Could you explain why $\int_{\gamma_R}\to 0$?

Comment: [See a full definition of a residue here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)).  I'll add an explanation of $\gamma_R$ to my answer.

Comment: That should cover everything

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. You've made a little typo: $$\int_{\gamma_R}=\int_0^\pi\frac{e^{iRe^{i\theta}}}{Re^{i\theta}}iR\;d\theta$$

Comment: I think there is another mistake: $$e^{-R\sin\theta}\ne e^{-R}e^{\sin\theta}=e^{-R+\sin\theta}$$

Comment: In addition, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty=2\pi i\;\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{z},z=0\right)$$

Comment: Whoops, I'll see if I can fix the $R \to \infty$ argument.  As for that last one: in fact, the $\frac 12$ should be there because the indented contour only takes us halfway around the circle

Comment: @oxabadfood in fact, it seems I should have simply used Jordan lemma.  I was close to proving it, but the fact that this last integral approaches zero is surprisingly subtle.