# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$$

---

**My start:**

Zero is a singular point,
Let's define $g(z):=(e^{iz})\big/z$

$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz=\\
\int_{-R}^{-r}\frac{e^{ix}}{x}dx+\int_{C_r^+}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz+\int_{r}^{R}\frac{e^{ix}}{x}dx+\int_{C_R^+}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz$$

$$=\int_{r}^{R}\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{x}dx+\int_{C_r^+}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz+\int_{C_R^+}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz$$

from here I'm stuck the final answer should be $\pi /2$

$$(*)\lim\limits_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r^+}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz$$

$$(**)\lim\limits_{R\to 0}\int_{C_r^+}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz$$

[image]

Comment: The LHS = 0 - no residues - as you surely know. You need to evaluate - again, as you surely know - the limits of $(*)$ and $(**)$. So write out the integrals explicitly. The integrals are over semi-circles: parametrize them by $\theta$: $z= re^{i\theta}$ and $z= Re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @peterag $\pi /2$, this is what the book says

Comment: Oh sorry - I misread the question: I thought you wanted the integral over the entire real line. Yes $\pi/2$. (I just edited out the offending line above.) Over the entire real line it is $\pi$.

Comment: May be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594641/computing-int-infty-infty-frac-sin-xx-mathrmdx-with-residue-calc

Comment: And: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833129/calculate-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxdx-by-integration-of-a-suitable-function?lq=1

Comment: @KimPeek Thanks I am voting to close my question as duplicate

Comment: and see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2